# Reading values of list maniuplated by javascript in code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have an asp.net listbox that I'm using javascrript to let the client reorder elements.  When the user presses a save button (not pictured below), how can I capture the new order of the items in the listbox?  myList always contains the original order.

```
   <script>        

     function MoveUp() {
            ....
   }
   </script>

<asp:ListBox ID="myList" runat="server" Height="112px" AutoPostBack="True"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Up" OnClientClick="MoveUp();return" false;" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Down" OnClientClick="MoveDown();return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in a hidden form field as the client reorders them. When the client hits the save button, grab that hidden field which you can use to identify the new order.

Using something like the jquery sortable plugin could make your life easier, as you won't need the up and down buttons.

Having said that, since your buttons will probably only be used for client side functionality, they really don't need to be (and shouldn't be asp.net buttons)